# Linux group / user permission issue

Tags: linux, permissions, redhat, users, groups

Redhat 5.5, logged in as root

I created a group dev-core

```
groupadd dev-core
```

Then I create a new user tony

```
useradd tony
```

I changed tony's password and added tony to group dev-core

```
usermod -a -G dev-core tony
```

Then, I created a directory /devel

```
mkdir /devel
```

I changed it's group to dev-core

```
chgrp dev-core /devel
```

I changed the directory's permission to this

```
drwxrwx--- 3 root dev-core
```

Now, when I login as tony and try to access /devel, I get a permissions denied message.

I don't understand why, the group that tony belongs to has full access to that directory.
Can anyone explain?

Comment: As user tony, type `id` (or `id tony` as someone else) and report back.  Also, what command do you mean by "access"?  You also must login to user tony fresh AFTER making the usermod change.

Comment: when logged in as tony, what is the output of 'id'?

Comment: `uid=501(tony) gid=502(tony) groups=502(tony),501(dec-core)`

Comment: @Seth: I needed to login again *facepalm*. It works now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must login to user tony fresh AFTER making the usermod change.